# GUI freez WPF Business application to display 10 millions records per second

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, performance

My requirement is to display about 10 millions records/sec in a WPF application on different grids and chart. it looks like WPF GUI thread is unable to catch up this much amount of data. 
    i am receiving the data on a separate thread (the network thread) and updating the view model collections by raising collection changed and property changed events from the network thread.
    Also the data updates are as frequent as the data additions like for 10 millions/records there can be 10 millions data updates.

```
The approach i am following is given below

Model Collection -> receives the data from network thread
Model Collection -> raises collection changed event
View Model -> on collection changed event dispatch the data to UI Thread.
```

Any solution i can avoid freezing the GUI with that much records to be displayed.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: @Sheridan you beat me to it. I was about to ask the same exact thing.

Comment: Who is capable of viewing that 10 million records per second?

Comment: question is how i can avoid freezing the gui with that much records have to display.

Comment: @HighCore... weren't we all? ;)

Comment: Your question sounds like "How to drive my car very fast without consuming petrol". Your UI thread is busy doing the work you assigned. Any solution? Yes, don't do that simple :)

Comment: @SriramSakthivel strangely WinForm version of the same application has no freezing issue? any idea whats wrong with WPF

Comment: Then you should post both codes, question is vague right now without code to see where is the problem

Comment: Post the relevant code and XAML.

Comment: First thing you should consider is that you only update the visible data that is shown to the user.

Comment: @DavidSdot only visible data is send to dispatcher. yes it is

Comment: have you already used a profiler?

Comment: no i didn't used profiler yet. any link to some profiler software ?

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid the UI freezing simply by *not* showing 10 million rows in your UI. No one is going to give you a ready made solution... you've got lots of work to do. However, I can put you on the right path. You have a few possible options.

There is something called `Virtualization` that is built into a number of WPF collection controls. This attempts to make it *appear* as if all of your items are in your control, but it really *silently* loads small groups of items that are in display and disposes of others that have just gone out of display. This is your simplest option and you can find out more from the [Optimizing Performance: Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716879%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) page on MSDN.

The only other option that I can think of is data paging. It works in pretty much the same way except that you'll have to manually implement the code and it won't appear as if all of the data is loaded... only one page of data will be loaded at a time. You can find a detailed description/tutorial in the [DataView Paging in WPF](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20463/DataView-Paging-in-WPF) page on CodeProject.

One final point that might help is that you should probably define quite a simple `DataTemplate` for the items, maybe even just a `Textblock`... if each item has a complicated UI to render, it will take that much longer. Good luck with displaying your 10 million rows.

Comment: i am using virtualization on Grids, data templates are complex but major hurdle is the chart i am showing. more than 70% of the dispatcher is used by the chart control.

Comment: There's not much that I can do about that.